# How can I omit the middle of a chain of methods?

Tags: ruby, alias-method-chain

Suppose I have a class with a `save` method, and three mixins which modify it using aliasing, e.g.

```
module Callbacks
  def save_with_callbacks
    callback :before_save
    save_without_callbacks
    end
  end

  alias_method_chain :save, :callbacks
end
```

and similarly for `save_with_transaction` and `save_with_timestamps`, mixed in in that order, so `MyModel#save` calls `save_with_timestamps`, which calls `save_with_transaction`, which calls `save_with_callbacks`, which finally calls the original `save`.

Now suppose I want to save without a transaction.  I can call `save_without_transaction`, but that doesn't call the code to set the timestamps.

How can I save my model with timestamps and callbacks, but no transaction?

I could reorder the mixins, but my question is about omitting the middle, rather than specifically transactions.  How can I omit the middle of a chain of methods?

NOTE - I've used RoR's alias_method_chain for brevity, but my question applies to ruby in general

Answer (score 2):

Your only option seems to be -- to me, anyway -- to provide a second calling chain that handles this functionality further up.  I don't think you can do this with aliasing; you're going to have to define a new method that calls the old method, instead - so something like:

1. MyModel#save <-save_with_timestamps <- save_with_transaction <- save_with_callbacks <-save.
2. MyModel#save_other <-save_with_timestamps_other <- save_with_callbacks_other <-save_other.

(As an aside, aren't long chains of aliases going to make your code very difficult to read?  Personally I think I would work hard to avoid them.)

Comment: Yes, they do sometimes make it difficult to read, but the Rails codebase makes heavy use of them.

Comment: Well, as my mother would say, "if the rails codebase jumped off a cliff, would you do it too?"   ...okay, she wouldn't have actually said that...  :)